# Are there usage limits on google places API photos?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I understand the usage limits for the Google places API.

However, once you have made a place details request, occasionally a location will have several photos available to it.

You can then retrieve the URL for these photos by using the following function:

```
photo.getUrl(maxWidth:200,maxHeight:200);
```

This works find and the actual URL of the image is returned.  No ajax request appears to be made to Googles API, it simply returns a URL which you can then dynamically add to your DOM.

The URL's returned are like so:

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-SG8x8m7avHc/UWm8kgkkKTI/AAAAAAAAAA8/6_wM5YoSnlk/w1280-h1280-s0/2013-04-13
```

What I need to know is if accessing these images has any kind of usage limit attached to it.

Does each view count as one Google Places API request?  Or are all views essentially free and it is only the initial Place details request which counts towards usage.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but it still isn't answered, so I'll try my best.

**Does accessing these images have any kind of usage limit attached to it?**

No, once you've successfully requested a place result using the Places API you are free to request as many image URLs relating to that result as you'd like with no usage limitations on the Places API itself.
However, Google will limit the number of images you may receive if you don't have a premium plan. So for instance, if you were to make 200 image URL requests for 'The Eiffel Tower', you might only receive up to 15 (or less) images if you're on a free plan. I know that sucks right.

**Does each view count as one Google Places API request? Or are all views essentially free and it is only the initial Place details request which counts towards usage**

If you're referring to image URL requests as a "view". Then the latter is true. Each image source requested won't increment the usage of the API.

If you're still uncertain here's a link to the [Place Photo requests method in the Google Maps Places API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_photos)

Answer (score -1):

Each page of results must be displayed before displaying the next page of results. Note that each search counts as a single request against your usage limits.

[refer here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=fr)

Comment: I understand that... but I need to know if there are usage limits on the singular, places PHOTO requests as described in my question.  I cannot find any mention in the documentation or even in their terms of service.  thanks anyway

Comment: I found this explaining abit about usage quota..this may help you https://developers.google.com/places/usage